# Python how to check if something is in a list

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am making a multiple choice game in Python I have a variable that selects a random number.

When the next box is clicked, I want the random number to change every time the button is clicked. Also, I want to append random to a list and then check if random is in the list. If so, random changes again to a different number, so that the questions don't repeat.

I want to change random to a random number again, however an integer has no attribute randint. How would I check to see if the random number is already in the list?

I have an `if` statement to tell me if it is clicked already, just need to figure out how to change random again after startup.

Comment: Where is your code? Why haven't you provided the full error traceback? Your question is *not* what the title (and parts of the question itself) implies.

Comment: Actually It is, I want to check if random is in a list. If so, change random again

Comment: This is why code and traceback is a good idea, particularly if your English isn't strong; it's unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem, which is very clear from the error message you should have included in your question, is that you do something like:

```
import random # 'random' refers to a module

...
random = random.randint(...) # 'random' now refers to an integer
```

Now you can't access any of the functionality of the `random` module. *Why on earth would you do that?!* **Give your variable a *different name* to the module.**

```
random_choice = random.randint(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it would affect the program

Comment: How could it possibly not have? What did you expect to happen if one name tried to refer to two different objects?

Comment: Now, how would I check if random is in a list, I .append random to my list when I click next, how do I check if random is already in my list?

Comment: `if random_choice in my_list`?!

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean *"it didn't work"*? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected output (provide input and expected and actual output)? **Edit your question** to include a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) of your code and a precise description of exactly how is fails to work.